# Ember Component keyboard events

Tags: ember.js

In my webapp I have a search field at the top (kinda like Facebook) which is an `input` field and a bootstrap dropdown for result suggestions. I would like to decouple it from the controller of its container into an Ember Component. But I don't understand how to pick up events from the input field. Right now the view picks up `submit` (there is no submit button) and `keyUp`/`keyDown`for navigating the dropdown. How do I listen to these events on a Component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Component the same way as you would View.

```
App.SearchFieldComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  value: "",
  keyUp: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert("You pressed key code " + e.keyCode);
  }
});
```

[Full jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nutezowe/2/edit).